# Explicit conversion of data in a Table Valued Parameter from .NET to T-SQL

Tags: .net, t-sql, sql-variant

I need to call a stored procedure from VB.NET that takes a table valued parameter. The table structure has three columns, one of which is an `sql_variant`.

The `DataTable` I want to pass to this SP has some `string`s inside the `sql_variant` column, which converts fine from T-SQL -> .Net, but not the other way around.

The problem is that it's converting `string` to `nvarchar(max)` which is incompatible with `sql_variant`, but as far as I can tell, a conversion to `nvarchar(len(s))` would be fine.

So, can I *explicitly* convert certain cells in a `DataTable` to a type that will *implicitly* convert to a finite length `nvarchar`? Or, can I alter how these .NET types are implicitly converted to SQL types?

Thanks in advance for any help!
Andy

Comment: I see I can set a `MaxLength` property on the problem `DataTable` column and call the SP fine, but this only works if the `DataType` of the column is `string`. Unfortunately other values in the `sql_variant` column will be of other types.

Comment: If anyone is interested, until I have a real solution I am working around this by splitting my table into rows with strings in the `sql_variant` column and those without. Then I can set `MaxLength` on the `string` table. In fact I appear to have to split into each separate datatype anyway as otherwise I get complaints that `Object` is not compatible with `sql_variant`.